# HTML/CSS position elements

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to do this:

[image]

and mine looks like this:

[image]

Not the most beautiful thing. 
My questions are:

1. We have a header with logo, search bar, menus and a button. How can i stack them all inline?
2. On the div with the background image - how can I position the headline like the one in the original site?

Comment: This is my code:
http://pastebin.com/P8HLCAFZ - html
http://pastebin.com/GkKcPGEL - css

Comment: plzz add your code

Comment: i did added it in the comment bellow.

Comment: unable to view image urls

Comment: add your code to your question, not in the comments. Also have a look at this page: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: If you INSPECT the page, you will get all your answers.

Comment: Can you post your code **and** images into your question, please - some of us, due to restrictions imposed by web filters (etc) cannot see your code or your images.

Answer (score 0):

1) Have a look at the [Navbar component](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar) documentation. Items should already be inline if implemented correctly. You can use the navbar-left and navbar-right classes to position items in the navbar.

2) You'll notice the large centre text starts at the same position as the navbar logo. This is because of the container class. I suggest you analyse some [examples](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#examples) to see how to correctly implement the container.

After that, if you're still struggling add your styles.css to your pastebin post or better still create a [Codepen](https://codepen.io/) - this would allow someone to be more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

1- you can write float:left; or float:right; ? look for this [float](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp)

2-for position an element you must create a relative div later inside create absolute div.. and you can specify settlement coordinates with top right bottom left.. look here [position](http://learnlayout.com/position.html)

Answer (score 0):

I would say float is not good practice to use . Unless you really have no choice to use.

But based on how I look at it. 
It's achievable using flex.

Put a display:flex on your main div
Then as for your other elements . Use display:flex-grow

It's advantageous using flex. ,  not only it wil solve your problem.  It makes your site responsive.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

```
[![if you need all navigation item in one line. you have to make display:inline-block,for navigation.

change your code to:

<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 nav-wrap">
                <ul class="pull-left"><li><a href="#" class="logo"></a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="pull-left">                  
                    <li class="formSearch">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Find Freelancers" id="searchButton">
                    </li>               
                    <li><a href="#">Browse</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">How it works</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="pull-right">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" class="signupHover">
                            <span class="icon signup"></span>
                            <a href="#">Sign Up
                            </a>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" class="loginHover">
                            <span class="icon login"></span>
                            <a href="#">Login</a>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <button type="button" id="buttonHeader">Become a freelancer</button>
            </div>

/*add below css*/

.nav-wrap ul li{display:inline-block;}][1]][1]
```

[image]